# Java Having classes take information from each other

Tags: java

Let's say you have two classes, one called `Main` and the other called `Second`. `Second` needs to take a variable from `Main` and `Main` needs to take a method from `Second`

Example:

```
public class Main 
{
  Second second = new Second();
  public int firstInt = 5;
  second.printThing();
}

public class Second 
{
    Main main = new Main();
    public void printThing() 
    {  
        System.out.println(main.firstInt);
    }
}
```

Since you can't do `Main main = new Main();` and `Second second = new Second;` without getting a stack overflow exception, what are you supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the instances of `Main` and `Second` should hold references to each other, you can pass references to the constructors :

`Main`'s constructor :

```
public Main (Second second)
{
    this.second = new Second (this);
}
```

`Second`'s constructor :

```
public Second (Main main)
{
    this.main = main;
}
```

If, as the names imply, `Second` depends on `Main` (i.e. no isntance of `Second` can exist without an enclosing instance of `Main`), you can define `Second` to be an inner class of `Main`, in which case it would implicitly hold an instance of the enclosing class `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this kind of initialization, add a setter for each class in the other and set after construction.

```
Main m = new Main();
Second s = new Second();
m.setSecond(s);
s.setMain(m);
```